# "Reduce" adds unrequested attributes to result

Tags: r, functional-programming

Contrast the following two code snippets:

1.

```
> a <- cbind(1,2)
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
> str(a)
 num [1, 1:2] 1 2
```

2.

```
> b <- Reduce(cbind, list(1,2))
> b
     init  
[1,]    1 2
> str(b)
 num [1, 1:2] 1 2
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "init" ""
```

According to the `Reduce` help page, i would expect `a` and `b` to be the same, but they're obviously not quite. Why is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of how `Reduce` calls `f` and how `cbind` creates column names. `Reduce` determines the initial value based on the values of the `init` and `right` args and stores that value in an object named `init`, which it also happens to update iteratively.

In your example, the following code in `Reduce` is where the difference occurs:

```
init <- x[[1L]]
ind <- ind[-1L]
for (i in ind) init <- f(init, x[[i]])
```

The default `cbind` argument, `deparse.level = 1` means that it tries to create `dimnames` via deparsing the object names passed to it (if they make sensible names).  If you want the `Reduce` output to be identical to calling `cbind` on single numbers, then set `deparse.level=0`.

```
> str(Reduce(function(x,y) cbind(x,y,deparse.level=0), list(1,2)))
 num [1, 1:2] 1 2
```

As an aside, calling `cbind` in a for loop is a bad idea because it must re-allocate memory on each iteration, leading to very slow code.  It's much better to allocate the full output object you expect (if you can) and then fill in the elements.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Joshua explains why you have a difference. I just show how to get the same output. Indeed you should initialize the init parameter to NULL:

```
 identical(Reduce(cbind, list(1,2),init=NULL),
           cbind(1,2))
 TRUE
```

And as aside is more efficient here to call :

```
 do.call(cbind,list(1,2))
```

Comment: Thanks. However, your solution only works if the columns are of length 1. Compare the result of

Reduce(cbind, list(c(1,2), c(3,4), NULL))

Comment: @EvanAad No it works fine. You should write this. `Reduce(cbind, list(c(1,2), c(3,4)), NULL)` ( your expression is wrong)

Comment: @EvanAad: To clarify, agstudy is setting `init=NULL`, which is a more concise (though perhaps less clear) way to work-around your issue.